# Magento Theme Installation gone wrong?

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento

I am trying to install the following Magento template into my online store:

http://www.magthemes.com/magento-themes/free-themes/fitness-magento-theme.html

I am using this theme as it closely resembles the design/layout that I am after (I will have to tweak the CSS after installation).

Here is what I have done so far:
Unzipped downloaded file
Transferred the following folders to my server:
        app\design\frontend\default\Fitness_1.1 **to**
/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/Fitness_1.1
        skin\frontend\default\ **to** /public_html/skin/frontend/default/Fitness_1.1

Gone to my sites Admin > System > Configuration > Design
Entered the following:

- Templates: Fitness_1.1
- Skin (Images / CSS): Fitness_1.1
- Layout: Fitness_1.1
- Default: default

The theme changed, images changed etc but the Layout is not right and some styles are incorrect, you can see what I mean here:

```
http://89.200.141.67/~skin/index.php/
```

Comment: Have cleared cache? Seems like it is missing

Comment: Yea I have cleared the Cache every time I make a change :(

Comment: From what I can see I appear to missing the following CSS files:

skin/frontend/base/default/css/reset.css

skin/frontend/base/default/css/boxes.css

skin/frontend/base/default/css/clears.css

skin/frontend/base/default/css/custom.css

skin/frontend/base/default/css/menu.css

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS files aren't loading.  Try explicitly setting the skin directory in:

Admin>System>Configuration>Design - Skin (Images/CSS) form field

Uncheck the use website checkbox and make sure that your Current Configuration Scope (the drop down on the top left) is correct.